# Adding drop shadow/elevation shadow on MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout in Android Kotlin

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, user-interface, material-design

This is my code for using Material Component's Text input layout.
I've tried multiple custom or default options to give it the desired layout but nothing is working
The code and screenshots can be found below:
my custom styles:

```
  <style name="CustomTextInputLayout" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox">
    <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:background">#FFFFFF</item>
    <item name="boxCornerRadiusTopStart">13dp</item>
    <item name="boxCornerRadiusTopEnd">13dp</item>
    <item name="boxCornerRadiusBottomStart">13dp</item>
    <item name="boxCornerRadiusBottomEnd">13dp</item>
    <item name="hintTextAppearance">@style/CustomHintTextAppearance</item>
</style>

<style name="CustomHintTextAppearance" parent="TextAppearance.Design.Hint">
    <item name="fontFamily">@font/poppins_med</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">16sp</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
    <item name="android:letterSpacing">0</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#777777</item>
</style>
```

My XML file code:

```
 <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/tilEmail"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/_5sdp"
            style="@style/CustomTextInputLayout">

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:autofillHints="emailAddress"
                android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                android:hint="@string/email"
                android:textSize="@dimen/_12sdp" />
        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

The resultant UI:
[image: 1]

The desired UI:

[image: 2]

Answer (score 0):

Add `app:hintEnabled="false"` in the `<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>...</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>` tag.

**Solution:**

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/tilEmail"
    style="@style/CustomTextInputLayout"
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/_5sdp"
    app:hintEnabled="false"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">
        ...
</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```